# Программирование attiny2313 на C

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, avr

Написал код на C++ для мк attiny2313 хотел бы узнать как этот код должен выглядеть на самом деле, потому что этот я полагаю  костыль тот еще

Суть кода: при нажатии на кнопку присоедененную к порту А 0b00000001 подается логическая 1 последовательно на порты В 0b00000001 - 0b00000100 когда счетчик достигает лимита, в данном случает 3, то все обнуляется и начинается заново.

```
#include <avr/io.h>


int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xff;
    int count = 0;

    while (1) 
    {
        if (PINA == 0b001)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                if (PINA == 0b000)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count <= 0)
            {
                count++;
                PORTB |= 1<<1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
                PORTB = 0b00000000;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут не костыль, тут код, который не делает, то что вы описываете.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian все хуже чем я думал.. Поможете мне с костылем? Какие ошибки? Или тут нечего исправлять и лучше сжечь?

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто же.

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xff;
    char count; // 8-битной переменной тут более чем достаточно

    while(1)
    {
        // ждём нажатия кнопки
        while (PINA != 0b001)
            ;
        // ждём отпускания кнопки
        while (PINA == 0b001)
            ;

        for (count = 0; count < 3; count++)
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << count;
            // тут нужна задержка.
            // изучить содержимое delay.h предлагаю самостоятельно
        }
        PORTB = 0;
    }
}
```